# Send an xml request to a remote service with java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, esb

I want to send the below xml request to an ESB endpoint http://abc.co.za:8000/service/abcdefg using java. I'm not really familiar with web services and ESB as I'm from Front End.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

```
Server Time: 11:02:58:028 / Workstation Time: Monday, 22 February 2016 - 11:02:57:703
[DEBUG] SENDING SOAP REQUEST
MethodID: ID_getSubmitRequest; UID=-4820428854312736237
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns2:getSubmitRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:AC_IDM_SUBMITREQUESTVi" xmlns="urn:com.virsa.ae.ejbutil">
<ns2:requestDetails>
<application/>
<company>STACK OVERFLOW</company>
<customField>
<CustomFieldsDTO>
<name>Users ID Number</name>
<value>6303066107089</value>
</CustomFieldsDTO>
</customField>
<department xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<emailAddress>ronny.ronny@stack.co.za</emailAddress>
<employeeType>STACK</employeeType>
<firstName>RONNY</firstName>
<functionalArea xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<lastName>RONNY</lastName>
<locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<location xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<managerTelephone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrEmailAddress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrFirstName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrLastName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<priority>HIGH</priority>
<requestReason xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<requestType>SYSTEM</requestType>
<requestorEmailAddress>None</requestorEmailAddress>
<requestorFirstName>None</requestorFirstName>
<requestorId>BP5151</requestorId>
<requestorLastName>None</requestorLastName>
<requestorTelephone>None</requestorTelephone>
<roles>
<RoleData>
<action>ADD</action>
<comments xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<roleId>ZCB_STACK</roleId>
<sysId/>
<validFrom>2016-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validFrom>
<validTo>9999-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validTo>
</RoleData>
</roles>
<sNCName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<telephone>0123456789</telephone>
<unsecureLogon>false</unsecureLogon>
<userId>BP111</userId>
<validFrom>2016-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validFrom>
<validTo>9999-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validTo>
</ns2:requestDetails>
</ns2:getSubmitRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple libraries which can help you accomplish this task. One of the options is Apache CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html.

Steps to accomplish this task:

- Use Apache CXF or another library to create a client JAR containing code to connect to the target SOAP service
- Include this library in your Java code / project
- Initialize the proxy to connect to the service (provided by generated client library)
- Populate your inputs
- Invoke call to SOAP endpoint and process output returned

Great example demonstrating this: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html